# Laravel 5.1 adding Form And Html Classes

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am new to Laravel and using Laravel 5.1.

> FatalErrorException in 88e08cd08566357f572303974c44bc50 line 4: Class
>   'Form' not found.

For the above exception I did some changes in my project:

```
. "require": { 
"php": ">=5.5.9",
 "laravel/framework": "5.1.",
 "laravelcollective/html": "5.1."
 },
```

Added in JSON and updated the JSON file.

In `config/app.php`:

```
'providers' => [ // ... Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class, // ... ],
```

In `config/app.php`:

```
'aliases' => [ // ... 'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class, 'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class, // ... ],
```

I have added this aliases, but it's still showing the above error. Please can anyone help me?

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autload` in the console on the root of your application.
This will reload the autoload to include the classes.

Also, can you show us the code in that specific view?

Comment: Did you install it after adding it to your `composer.json`? You have to run `composer update` to install it.

Answer (score 1):

just you have to autoload your composer file.Reason is you added new class to required array  in composer.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

[Source and help for composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md)